# Rails 3 mapping sub resources to root with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, subdomain

I've got a model for sites that looks like:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :resource_1
  has_one :resource_2
  has_one :resource_3
  has_many :resource_4
end
```

I've got subdomains set up following the method outlined in http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3. So that if I visit http://subdomain.myapp.com it finds the site by name (assuming subdomain is the site's name) and displays the page normally at /sites/:id/resource_1.

I can still access all the other sub-resources of site from there, but I get a url that looks like http://subdomain.myapp.com/sites/:id/resource_name/:resource_id and I'd like to be able to set up routes that look like http://subdomain.myapp.com/resource_name/:resource_id.

I'm sure the proper terminology is just escaping it, but not really having the language to describe it concisely has made googling for a solution unfruitful. Any and all replies are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's just occurred to me that shallow routing may be a valid solution since I no longer need the /sites/:id to determine the current site.

Comment: Shallow routing wont work as I'd like to be able to preserve the singular case/no id on has_one relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a method to the application controller to get site by subdomain, then used shallow routing requiring site to be present.